# Cordova plugin not being loaded into the DOM

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) Cordova plugin in one of my Ionic apps. I've installed it with:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.git
```

And set up the demo as in the example. However, it's not being loaded. As in the README, you should invoke it with:

```
window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation
```

However, it is undefined. What's the correct way to install/invoke it?

Comment: have you waited for the deviceready event before using the plugin?

Comment: I'm running it inside of `$ionicPlatform.ready` which is triggered on `deviceready`.

Comment: I am not familiar with ionic? But are you sure that the ready() function is triggered by deviceready? can you try to to put the plugin API explicitly in the deviceready call and see if it still gives an error?

Comment: Opening up the developer console and displaying the window.plugins variable shows undefined, so thats not the problem.

Comment: did you rebuild the project after adding the plugin?